# Dimension of Tensor Product Space should be $\leq \dim(V)+\dim(W)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces of dimensions $m$ and $n$ over the same field $F$.

$V \otimes W$ is defined as the vector space of equivalence classes of vector space $F(V \times W)$ with bases as the tuples of form $(v,w)$ under the relation specified by:
$$
\begin{align}
(v_1 + v_2, w)&=(v_1, w)+(v_2, w)\\
(v, w_1+w_2)&=(v, w_1)+(v, w_2)\\
(sv,w)&=s(v,w)\\
(v,sw)&=s(v,w)
\end{align}
$$

Now in the following, I try to construct a representation of each equivalence class.

Let

$$z = a_1(v_1,w_1)+a_2(v_2, w_2)+ ... + a_n(v_n, w_n) \in F(V \times W)$$

Then:

$$
\begin{align}
z &\sim a_1(v_1,w_1)+a_2(v_2, w_2)+ ... + a_n(v_s, w_s) \qquad (1)\\
  &\sim (a_1v_1,w_1)+(a_2v_2, w_2)+ ... + (a_sv_s, w_s) \qquad (2)\\
  &\sim (a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_sv_s, w_1+w_2+...+w_s)
\end{align}
$$
where, $a_i \in F, v_i \in V, w_i \in W$ for $i=1,2, ..., s$.

Now the additions, are in original vector spaces, $V$ and $W$, rather than $F(V\times W)$, so we can just perform the addition and get some element $v$ of $V$ in the first slot and some element $w$ of $W$ in the second slot of the tuple.

So we see that the equivalence class of any $z \in F(V \times W)$ can be represented by $(v,w)$, where $v \in V$ and $w \in W$. But are these representations, unique?

In going from step $(1)$ to $(2)$, each of the $a_i$'s could have been moved in front of either $v_i$ or $w_i$, and the equivalence class would still have been the same. But, the final vectors in the two slots of the tuple would have been different. This suggests there are different representations of the same equivalence class.

In other words, we may not have unique equivalence classes corresponding to each tuple of the form $(v,w)$. So, we let $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_m\}$ and $\{ w_1, w_2, ..., w_n \}$ be a particular basis of $V$ and $W$, and proceed further:

$$
\begin{align}
(v,w) &\sim (\sum_{i} \alpha_i v_i, \sum_{j} \beta_j w_j)\\
      &\sim \sum_{i,j} (\alpha_i v_i, \beta_j w_j)\\
      &\sim \sum_{i,j} \alpha_i \beta_j (v_i, w_j)
\end{align}
$$

Previously we showed that all equivalence classes had a representation: $(v,w)$. And now, we have shown that all equivalence classes have a representation of the form $\sum_{i,j} \alpha_i \beta_j (v_i, w_j)$. As the set:

$$\{(v_i, w_j) | i \in [m], j \in [n]\}$$

spans the equivalence classes, and as there are at most $m+n$ variables that we choose here, ($m$ $\alpha_i$'s and $n$ $\beta_j$'s), I don't see how the Tensor product could possibly have dimension as $m \times n$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I agree with your (1) and (2), but your next line is wrong.

Comment: Dimensions multiply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're allowed to do
$$
(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)\sim(v_1+v_2,w),\qquad
(v,w_1)+(v,w_2)\sim(v,w_1+w_2)
$$
but it's generally false that
$$
(v_1,w_1)+(v_2,w_2)\sim(v_1+v_2,w_1+w_2)
$$
which you are using in the line after $(2)$.

If you denote by $K$ the subspace of $F(V\times W)$ generated by the given relations, then the idea is that the map $\tau\colon V\times W\to F(V\times W)/K=V\otimes W$ defined by
$$
\tau(v,w)=(v,w)+K=v\otimes w
$$
is *bilinear*. It' *cannot* be also a linear map if you endow the set $V\times W$ with the componentwise operations, unless one of the spaces is the trivial vector space. You may try your hand on this exercise.